# Enable Windows Failover Cluster With Zentyal Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, failover, failovercluster, zentyal

currently i have one domain controller with zentyal (Community Edition).  And i have 2 node already connected to domain.

So i setup Windows Failover Cluster, but i always got failed validate with error message `access denied`. Earlier i already create use with administrator level domain controller and this user already join to administrator group on every each node.

but still i got error `access denied` on validate step when i setup windows failover cluster.

this is impact or limitation from zentyal or need more configuration on zentyal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zentyal doesn't have Failover Cluster listed as a supported feature. You can try installing Active Directory and use Zentyal as an additional one.
https://zentyal.com/news/how-to-zentyal-as-an-additional-domain-controller-of-a-windows-domain-video-tutorial/

Comment: hi thanks for advice.so do you mean acctually I should need Domain Controller from Windows ? and then zentyal as a secondary or backup from Windows Domain Controller ?